# How do I beat Volcano?

Tags: shadow-fight-2

What is the best Strategy for fighting the **Boss** **Volcano** in ***Shadow Fight 2***?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First You have to take down all of his shields.
**When you fight him after you take down all of his shields**

- First when he uses his spin attack use leg sweeps
- Second before he tries to teleport if you are near him, hit him with an attack.
- Dodge his projectiles
- When he uses magic roll or do a forward flip to get out of the way.